# Java: Effeciently keep track of used objects

Tags: java, search, sorting, duplicates

I have a program that collects objects over time. Those objects are often, but not always duplicates of objects the program has already received. The number of unique objects can sometimes be up in the tens of thousands. As my lists grow, it takes more time to identify whether an object has appeared or not before.

My current method is to store everything in an ArrayList, al; use Collections.sort(al); and use Collections.binarySearch(al, key) to determine whether I've used an object. Everytime I come across a new object I have to insert and sort however.

I'm wondering if there's just a better way to do this. Contains tends to slow up too quickly. I'm looking for something as close to O(1) as possible.

Thanks much.

This is java. For the purpose of understanding what I'm talking about, I basically need a method that does this:

```
public boolean objectAlreadyUsed(Object o) {
  return \\ Have we seen this object already?

}
```

Comment: You could just use a HashSet or a HashMap instead of an ArrayList.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using an `ArrayList`, why wouldn't you use a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) implementation (likely a [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html))? You'll get [constant-time lookup](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29), no sorting needed.

**N.B.** your objects will need to [correctly override `hashCode()` and `equals()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java).

Comment: I looked up hashList. :( \\ figures it was HashSet. Thanks... trying it out.

Comment: I can accept this in a few minutes. Worked perfectly. Luckily my objects this time are strings so no extra implementation necessary... **waits for click to tick down...

Answer (score 6):

This begs the question - why not use a data structure that doesn't allow duplicates (e.g. [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html))? If you attempt to [add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29) a duplicate item, the method will return `false` and the data structure will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the objects have correct `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods, and store them in a `HashSet`. Lookup then becomes constant time.

If retaining unwanted objects becomes an issue, by the way, you could consider using one of the many `WeakHashSet` implementations available on the Internet -- it will hold the objects but still allow them to be garbage collected if necessary.

Comment: I do need to retain all objects this time, its important to the data I'm spitting out, but good to know. You learn so much and you think you know everything there is to know about Java... and then you don't. :)